# Finding $\text{Res}(f,0)$ where $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2\sin(z)}$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits, residue-calculus

I am trying to determine the residue of $z=0$ where $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2\sin(z)}$.

I have determined that $z=0$ is a pole of order $3$. Hence to compute the residue, I use $$\text{Res}(f,0)=\frac{1}{2}\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}\left(\frac{z}{\sin(z)}\right).$$
I am convinced I am doing something incorrect, as the calculations become very convoluted. I have computed that $$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}=\frac{z\sin^3(z)-2\sin^2(z)\cos(z)+2z\sin(z)\cos^2(z)}{\sin^4(z)},$$ but am unsure of how to further compute the residue, as I'm unable to solve this limit.

**edit**

I have solved the problem via the repeated use of L'Hopitals rule, but this took the work of computing some ugly limits. Is there another way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the residue at $z=0$ for complex function $1/(z^2\sin z$)](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/366954/finding-the-residue-at-z-0-for-complex-function-1-z2-sin-z)

Comment: You can let the moderators take care of it I think, now that somebody has taken the time to answer. But yes the existing question was an exact duplicate with a good answer.  Solving via L'Hospital is of course possible but I think the moral here is that when dealing with residues involving elementary analytic functions it's a good idea to try messing around with their series expansions, since you only care about the first few coefficients it is in practice often much simpler.

Comment: @BadamBaplan Vote to duplicate is nice. There are two good answers there :)

Answer (score 2):

$$\sin z=z-\dfrac{1}{3!}z^3+\dfrac{1}{5!}z^5-\dfrac{1}{7!}z^7+\cdots$$
then
\begin{align}
\dfrac{1}{z^2\sin z}
&= \dfrac{1}{z^3\left(1-\dfrac{1}{3!}z^2+\dfrac{1}{5!}z^4-\dfrac{1}{7!}z^6+\cdots\right)} \\
&= \dfrac{1}{z^3}\left(1+\dfrac{1}{6}z^2+(\dfrac{1}{36}-\dfrac{1}{120})z^4+\cdots\right) \\
&= \dfrac{1}{z^3}+\dfrac{1}{6z}+\dfrac{7z}{120}+\cdots
\end{align}
s0 $a_{-1}=\dfrac16$.

Comment: I'm curious to know how you derived the residue so fast. I got the same answer using my approach, but it took a full page of nasty limits.

Comment: Some details didn't mention like division.

Comment: Yes, but why is the residue the coefficient of the $z^{-1}$ term and not any other term?

Comment: by definition of residue $:-)$.

Comment: The Cauchy integral theorem requires that the first and last terms vanish, so we have $a_{-1}$ term leftover

Comment: Ah I see. In general, is the the coefficient of the term $(z-z_0)^{-1}$ the residue for a singularity $z_0$?

Comment: Is this statement dependent on the type of singularity? Or is it sufficient for isolated, poles and essential singularities?

Comment: Residue could be found in isolated, poles and essential singularities as well. Indeed the role of residue is calculating the integral $\int f(z) dz$.

Comment: could you please tell me how you proceeded from the third last line to the second last line. Why did the terms in the bracket change?

Comment: I think you mean the division. Do it like division in polynomials.

Comment: Are you able to perhaps add a step or two? I am not getting the same results.

Comment: I can't type division in TeX form, there is another formula for finding some primitive terms **just** in such case, using geometric series $$\dfrac{1}{1-z}=1+z+z^2+\cdots$$

Comment: $$\dfrac{1}{1-\color{red}{\left(\dfrac{1}{3!}z^2-\dfrac{1}{5!}z^4+\dfrac{1}{7!}z^6-\cdots\right)}} $$

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2}(\frac z{\sin z})=\frac{\partial}{\partial z}\frac{\sin z-z\cos z}{\sin^2 z}=\frac{(\sin z-z\cos z)2\sin z\cos z+z\sin^3 z}{\sin^4 z}=\frac{2\cos z(\sin z-z\cos z)}{\sin^3 z}+\frac z{\sin z}=\frac{2\cos z}{\sin^2 z}-\frac{2z\cos^2 z}{\sin^3 z}+\frac z{\sin z}$.

Now for the middle term (as the other two are easier) , we use L'Hôpital's:  $\frac{2\cos^2 z-4 z\cos z\sin z}{3\sin^2 z\cos z}=\frac{2\cos z}{3\sin^2 z}-\frac{4z}{3\sin z}$

Now for the first term (as the other is easy), L'Hôpital's again:  $-\frac1{3\cos z}\to-\frac13$.

The limit of each term is now easy:

$-1-(-\frac13-\frac43)+1=\frac13$.

I get a limit of $\frac13$.